# iPhone SDK Clearing Multiple Text Fields at Once

Tags: iphone

If I have multiple text fields and would like to have a button that clears all text fields at once, what tutorials or direction should I look into doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by putting a handler on that button (Touch Up Inside event). Then, you have several approaches.

You can have an outlet for each text box, in the handler, you set the text property to nil for each.

You can scroll through the subviews collection of your view, and for each textbox you encounter, set set the text property to nil. This leaves no textbox on the view untouched. You will have to recurse if the view hierarchy is nested.

You can assign numeric tags in a certain range to each textbox, then you go through the range, retrieve the view by tag and set text to nil. This is how it's normally done in Win32 API, in case you care.

Comment: Apple tutorials would probably suggest that you do it the first way.

Comment: so the property would just say nil once, and i connect that to each text field? or does the property say TextField1, TextField2, TextField3 == nil, etc?

Comment: @HollerTrain: it goes: TextField1.text = TextField2.text = TextField3.text = nil;

Comment: @Kevin: depends on how many of those. If, I'd say, 10 or more - even Apple would rather use a loop.

Comment: like this? [txtUserName.text = txtUserName2.text = txtUserName3.text = txtUserName4.text = txtUserName5.text = nil];?

Comment: Hey thanks Seva. That was actually very easy with your help. Hope this helps someone in the future (http://screencast.com/t/YmYxMjc3).

Comment: Remove the []'s. You're assigning to a property, not calling a method.

Answer (score 2):

If you need blanket clear textfields often, it might be worth your time to create a subclass of UITextField with a `clearAllText` method. Then you can just broadcast the message to all the subviews in a view and the ones with the method will clear their text and the one's without will ignore it. (More neatly, you can check that individual subviews respond to the message before sending it.) That way, you don't have to track which objects are textfields and which are not. Very useful if you have a dynamic layout wherein the number of textfields changes.

Comment: A property is a getter and a setter. Can you broadcast a setter call with nil as the argument?